# PHP Datetime Function date convert

Tags: php, function, datetime, time, datetime-format

I have a problem. How can i solve this problem.

My Function

```
function time_elapsed_string($datetime, $full = false) {
$now = new DateTime;
$ago = new DateTime($datetime);
$diff = $now->diff($ago);
$diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
$diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;
$string = array(
    'y' => 'year',
    'm' => 'mounth',
    'w' => 'week',
    'd' => 'day',
    'h' => 'hour',
    'i' => 'minute',
    's' => 'sencond',
);
foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
    if ($diff->$k) {
        $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? '' : '');
    } else {
        unset($string[$k]);
    }
}
if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
    return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just time';
}

$dateok="2022-05-15 09:22:16"; // year-mounth-date hours:minute:second 

echo time_elapsed_string($dateok);
```

I want convert data turkish time but my function calculating wrong .

(I Think is $now = new DateTime; my date format does not match maybe We Have GMT+3 Turkish Time ... I Dont know)

Note : **$dateok has a variable value.**

---

***EXAMPLE 1 :***

Suppose now is (current time ) **2022-05-15 10:47:00**

Suppose my date is namely $dateok = **2022-05-15 10:46:00**

**output // 2 hour ago** -> this is false -> **must be : 1 minute ago**

---

***EXAMPLE 2 :***

Suppose now is (current time ) **2022-05-15 10:47:00**

Suppose my date is namely $dateok = **2022-05-14 10:47:00**

**output // 21 hour ago** -> this is false -> **must be : 1 day ago**

SOLUTION :  add date_default_timezone_set('') and problem solved.

Comment: You need to improve your explanation

Comment: I updated my problem explanation

Comment: You just need to set your timezone firs, as I did here https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/undefined/php/php81/e7cd802624f2e8e6b073c6581567bec1/

Comment: why the heck are you fiddling around in the diff-result?